# Navigate to parent folder[BATCH]

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder where is the batch file.

**MyFolder\Folder1** **-** **contains the batch file**

The question is if the batch file can navigate to Myfolder(parent folder).

**I want the script written in the easiest way please.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move to the parent directory with

```
cd ..
```

or

```
cd %cd%\..
```

But it really depends on what you want to do. You may perhaps want to navigate to the batch's parent directory when the current directectory is **not** the directory in which the batch is located.